# text-properties: How to add a face + additional face attributes

Tags: faces

In this scenario, there exists one or more faces for a particular condition named `"foo"`.  When the condition changes to the name of `"bar"`, the goal is to add an additional face attribute such as `:strike-through t`.  How can this be done without explicitly defining separate faces for both conditions?  E.g., eliminate the need to define `my-face+strike-through`.

```lisp
(defface my-face
  '((t (:foreground "red")))
  "Doc-string"
  :group 'my-faces)

(defface my-face+strike-through
  '((t (:foreground "red" :strike-through t)))
  "Doc-string"
  :group 'my-faces)

(let ((txt "foo"))
  (if (equal txt "bar")
    (add-text-properties 0 (length txt) (list 'face 'my-face) txt)
    (add-text-properties 0 (length txt) (list 'face 'my-face+strike-through) txt))
  txt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A face spec can be a face defined with `defface`, or it can be a list of face attributs and their values.

You can apply multiple face specs (multiple faces) to the same text (in a string or buffer).  Those multiple faces are *merged* - their attributes are combined.

```lisp
(defvar foo "foo")
(defvar bar "bar")

(add-text-properties 0 3 (list 'face 'my-face) foo)
(add-text-properties 0 3 (list 'face '(my-face (:strike-through t))) bar)
```

See the Elisp manual, nodes [Defining Faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Faces.html) and [Displaying Faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Faces.html). See also node [Face Remapping](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html).